# Поиск отсутствующих данных

Tags: python, python-3.x, arcgis

Есть скрипт для поиска отсутствующих данных: берёт цифровой код из одной таблицы и проверяет есть ли такой же код в другой таблице

```
fc = "Build_pol"  #данные которые нужно найти
fc_1 = "Building_tab" #слой или таблица в котором нужно найти совпадения
field = "KI_NUMBER" #столбец в котором ищутся данные

cursor = arcpy.SearchCursor(fc)
cursor_1 = arcpy.SearchCursor(fc_1)
b=[] 
for row_1 in cursor_1:
        b.append(row_1.getValue(field))
for row in cursor:
    a=row.getValue(field)
    if a not in b:
        print ('Совпадений нет - {}'.format(a))
```

Есть ли более изящный вариант поиска отсутствующих данных ? На сколько я понимаю find не подойдет для этого

Comment: у вас [tag:python-3.x] потому что после `print` идут круглые скобки

Comment: Обычно это на уровне БД делается, а не в скрипте.

Comment: @CrazyElf к бд нету доступа

Comment: @Grechkin26 Тогда нормальный у вас вариант, только вместо `list` надо использовать `set`: `b = set()`, иначе если `b` будет большим, поиск будет медленно идти.